# How to scroll sideways on morph menu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-thaumcraft

How to scroll sideways on morph menu? I play on a server and couldn't find out - noone knew.

Answer (score 0):

Though I found a wikia site dedicated to morph: http://minecraft-modsmc.wikia.com/wiki/Morph_Mod

You shift and use your scroll wheel.